# Validation of deploy mode

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

Would like to understand how to validate/check/test mode of deployment (Client mode or cluster mode) in Standalone cluster.I understand by setting values in conf, I can view it on spark Web UI environment variables but it does not help me in understanding impact of deployment mode. I tried running application from machine on which master/executor were running and from local laptop. But I could not find difference in execution.

Please note my cluster setup is on VirtualBox.

.set("deploy-mode", "client") or .set("deploy-mode", "cluster")

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37027732/apache-spark-differences-between-client-and-cluster-deploy-modes?rq=1

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov:I understand difference in cluster or client mode but i wanted to practically test it. From Above link, I think you trying to point out two things supervise option and copying jar manually in case of cluster mode. If yes, Please let me know how to reset driver in supervise scenario. Also let me know if my understanding is in incorrect then how should we practically test it.